# React JS, Updating a specific field, rendered from a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a loop (using `Array.map`) that outputs a bunch of forms with unique id's / keys. I now need to be able to edit/submit them uniquely.

All fields should be empty by default.

At the moment, I haven't figured out how to differentiate them onChange causing the state to be the same on ALL fields.

I need each field to update separately with its unique data.

Basically, I've got a bunch of "Sections" and inside of each "Section", I want to write post tasks.

I'm running the latest React JS and I'm using Hooks.

I've structured this part of the app as follows:

Parent (gets the data of the sections from DB and puts it into a state)

Section List (uses props from Parents and Maps the inputs and some design stuff)

Input Forms, rendered by the map. (These are the forms I want unique.)

Here's code that I've tried. Including, indexing and getting the unique _id's etc.

Inside the Parent

```
    <ProjectSections Sections={getProjectSections}
    SetSections={setProjectSections} />
```

Section List

```
function ProjectSections(props) {

  const setSectionData = props.SetSections;
  const SectionData = props.Sections;

  const blankTask = {taskname: ""}
  const [task, setTask] = useState({taskname: ""})
  const [taskidx, setTaskidx] = useState({idx: ""})
  console.log(task, taskidx)


const taskInputChange = (e) => {
  // onChange={e => [props.SetTask({taskname: e.currentTarget.value})][props.SetIDX(e.currentTarget.dataset.idx)]}

  e.preventDefault();
  setTask({taskname: e.target.value})
  console.log(e.target.dataset.idx)
  // const updatedTasks = [e.currentTarget.dataset.idx][e.target.className] = e.target.value;
  // setTask(updatedTasks)



 // updatedTasks[e.target.dataset.idx][e.target.c] = e.target.value;
  // console.log(updatedTasks)
}

const addTask = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

// This is where I will post to the database



  };


  const TheSectionList = SectionData.map((project, idx) =>

    <div key={project._id}>


          <p className="is-size-5">{project.sectionname}</p>

        <AddTaskForm
            IDX={idx}
            Submit={addTask}
            SetTask={setTask}
            theTask={task}
            SetIDX={setTaskidx}
            inputChange={taskInputChange}
             /> 

        </div>



  )

  return (
    <>
    {TheSectionList}
    </>
  )
}


export default ProjectSections;
```

The Form (AddTaskForm)

```
function AddTaskForm(props) {


    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={props.Submit} >

    <input 
    onChange={props.inputChange}
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Create Homepage" 
    value={props.theTask.taskname}
    data-idx={props.IDX}
     />
  </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Task"  />

  </div>
</div>          
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default AddTaskForm;
```

As it is right now, whenever I update (write into) any form, they ALL change, despite the `idx` showing correctly in the console log.

Comment: I think you're missing alot of details on your App. Do you mind creating a codesandbox to see how all this comes together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of your application can be alot larger than what you've suggested in your original post.

In any case, I've created a moderately sized prototype for you. This should demonstrate how to encapsulate each `Section`, so that their task-list and functionality are isolated to their own context.

See here for: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-pond-ld463)

In total there are only 3 child-components and 1 Parent.

### index.js

*The main sections-state is managed here. All state-updating functions are derived from here.*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AddSectionForm from "./AddSectionForm";
import ProjectSections from "./ProjectSections";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      sectionName: "Chores",
      tasks: [{ id: 1, desc: "Take out trash", editting: false }]
    }
  ]);

  const addNewSection = sectionName => {
    let newSection = {
      id: keyRandomizer(),
      sectionName: sectionName,
      tasks: []
    };

    setSections([...sections, newSection]);
  };

  const addNewTask = (sectionId, taskName) => {
    let newTask = {
      id: keyRandomizer(),
      desc: taskName,
      editting: false
    };

    let allSectionsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sections));
    let sectionIndex = allSectionsCopy.findIndex(
      section => section.id === sectionId
    );
    let sectionToUpdate = allSectionsCopy[sectionIndex];

    sectionToUpdate.tasks = [...sectionToUpdate.tasks, newTask];

    setSections([...allSectionsCopy]);
  };

  const updateTaskDesc = (desc, sectionId, taskId) => {
    let allSectionsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sections));
    let sectionIndex = allSectionsCopy.findIndex(
      section => section.id === sectionId
    );
    let sectionToUpdate = allSectionsCopy[sectionIndex];
    let taskIndex = sectionToUpdate.tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === taskId);
    let taskToUpdate = sectionToUpdate.tasks[taskIndex];

    taskToUpdate.desc = desc;

    setSections([...allSectionsCopy]);
  };

  const toggleTaskEditMode = (sectionId, taskId) => {
    let allSectionsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sections));
    let sectionIndex = allSectionsCopy.findIndex(
      section => section.id === sectionId
    );
    let sectionToUpdate = allSectionsCopy[sectionIndex];
    let taskIndex = sectionToUpdate.tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === taskId);
    let taskToUpdate = sectionToUpdate.tasks[taskIndex];

    taskToUpdate.editting = !taskToUpdate.editting;

    setSections([...allSectionsCopy]);
  };

  const keyRandomizer = () => {
    let randomKey = "";
    let characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      randomKey += characters.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
      );
    }
    return randomKey;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddSectionForm addNewSection={addNewSection} />
      <ProjectSections
        sections={sections}
        addNewTask={addNewTask}
        updateTaskDesc={updateTaskDesc}
        toggleTaskEditMode={toggleTaskEditMode}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### AddSectionForm.js

*Just adds new sections to be used in the overall sections-state.*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function AddSectionForm(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.addNewSection(text);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Create Homepage"
        value={text}
      />

      <input className="add-section-button" type="submit" value="Add Section" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default AddSectionForm;
```

### ProjectSections.js

*Iterate over each section to initiate a unique Section component*

```
import React from "react";
import Section from "./Section";

function ProjectSections(props) {
  const createSections = () => {
    const { sections, addNewTask, toggleTaskEditMode, updateTaskDesc } = props;

    return sections.map(section => {
      return (
        <Section
          section={section}
          addNewTask={addNewTask}
          updateTaskDesc={updateTaskDesc}
          toggleTaskEditMode={toggleTaskEditMode}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return <div>{createSections()}</div>;
}
export default ProjectSections;
```

### Section.js

*Where all the magic happens.*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Section = ({
  section,
  addNewTask,
  toggleTaskEditMode,
  updateTaskDesc
}) => {
  const [newTaskName, setTaskName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    addNewTask(section.id, newTaskName);

    setTaskName("");
  };

  const handleUpdateTaskDesc = (e, sectionId, taskId) => {
    updateTaskDesc(e.target.value, sectionId, taskId);
  };

  const handleToggle = (sectionId, taskId) => {
    toggleTaskEditMode(sectionId, taskId);
  };

  const handleNewTaskChange = e => {
    setTaskName(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="section">
      <h4>{section.sectionName}</h4>
      {section.tasks.map(task => {
        return !task.editting ? (
          <div className="task-item">
            <label>{task.desc}</label>
            <button onClick={() => handleToggle(section.id, task.id)}>
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="task-item">
            <input
              value={task.desc}
              onChange={e => handleUpdateTaskDesc(e, section.id, task.id)}
            />
            <button onClick={() => handleToggle(section.id, task.id)}>
              Done
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}

      {/* Add new task */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder="Add Task"
          name="task"
          onChange={handleNewTaskChange}
          value={newTaskName}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!newTaskName.length}>
          Add Task
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section;
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. You actually covered what I needed and more! 
Thanks so much Christopher. Gonna build this into my app now. Still a React Dev.

Cheers!

Comment: @RonaldLangeveld you're welcome friend! Thank you for the kind words. I'm happy this was useful to you. When you have the chance, please consider upvoting and marking this as the solution. :)

Comment: This was pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks @Chad glad to see this is still useful 2 years later :)